# json parsing function returns weird package name

Tags: java, android, json

I have made a JSON parsing class which returns a string. when i set the text of a textview to the string, it print 'com.test.app.JSONParser@41eddbf8'

What's going wrong?

Heres the parsing class

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

/**
 * Created by Vaibhav on 8/9/13.
 */
public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url[0]);
        //httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result;
        try {
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        inputStream = entity.getContent();
        // json is UTF-8 by default
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        result = sb.toString();
        return result;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("com.test.app.JSONParser", "JSON ERROR:" + e.toString());
        return null;
    }
    finally {
        try{if(inputStream != null)inputStream.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
    }
}
}
```

I call the function like

```
String jsonString = new JSONParser().execute(jsonURL).toString();
```

I dont know why im getting the weird response. Thanks

EDIT:

So since i wanted the output in a fragment, i just ended up using

[How to get the result of OnPostExecute() to main activity because AsyncTask is a separate class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)

to return the json string to the calling fragment so i could manipulate it from there.

EDIT 2:

OMG!! it was so easy. I wasted so much time on this! So for anyone else who has this problem, all you need to do is add .get() at the end of the call.

So: `String jsonString = new JSONParser().execute(jsonURL).get();` was my call and it worked! I didnt even need a onPostExecute block in my asynctask.

Comment: What does the `execute` method return?

Comment: when i dont put .toString(), it gives me an error saying it gets an `android.os.AsyncTask <java.lang.String, java.lang.Void, java.lang.String>`

Comment: See my answer below, why are you using an AsyncTask if you want the result synchronously?

Comment: Becuase if i didnt i got the networkOnMainThread error.

Comment: So then modify your application so to make the result handling async. What are you doing with the result of the parsed JSON?

Comment: i plan to manipulate it and make cards out of it using cardsui by fima. but for now im trying to print it in a textview to see if it works

Comment: So move that logic into `onPostExecute(final String json)`. You have the json, make it into cards and print it to the textview from that method.

Comment: alrightly then thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `doInBackground` method does not return its result when you call execute, instead the result is passed to the `onPostExecute` method. It looks like you are using an `AsyncTask` incorrectly. Usually you'd do something with the result in `onPostExecute` that needs the main thread.

What you are seeing is the `toString` output on the `JSONParser` class, since an `AsyncTask` will return `this` when you call `execute`.

Comment: Ok, so i have added the onPostExecute, but how do i make it return the string to the caller since its void? Thanks

Comment: You can't, the purpose of an AsyncTask is to break the connection between the caller and the execution process. If you want to do this synchronously simply remove the code from inside the `AsyncTask` and call it from a regular function call.

Comment: I was getting the `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` before when it was a function i tried changing it to asynctask to try to fix it

Answer (score 0):

You are printing an object whose `toString` method is most likely not overriden to print a pretty output.

If `JSONParser` is your own class, then override the toString method to print the output in a desired way. If JSONParse is not your class then you need to find how to print the output properly from the api doc.

Comment: its my class, the big chunk of code i have in the OP. But i think the problem is it isnt returning the response properly and is actually returning the function. Know how to fix it?

Comment: @VaibhavAggarwal What is the return type of execute methods?Can you share your execute method code?

Comment: `execute` is not his code, it's part of `AsyncTask` and it simply calls `doInBackground` on a different thread.